# "I don't give up to you" works in the following meaning?

Tags: phrase-usage, phrase-request

As a trainer if I want to encourage my student that tells me that he cannot anymore (and I know that he can...) can I tell him "I don't **give up to** **you** I know that you can more! Keep workout a little bit more"?

N.b. It can be due to training of sports but it can be also due practicing of language or any learning subject when I see that the student can more but it's a matter of laziness.

Answer (score 3):

[The idiomatic way to say it in English is *giving up* **on** someone or something.](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/give%20up%20on%20(someone%20or%20something))  I would say it as

> I'm not giving up on you!

The use of the present continuous "I'm not giving up" makes more sense if we're talking about something happening right now; using the simple present "I don't give up" makes more sense if we're talking about a general situation or general truth.

---

As an aside, there are a couple other errors in your original sentences; we only use the modal *can* with a verb, so *"I know that you can more!"* should be "I know that you can **do** more!"

Also, *workout* is a noun, but you want to urge your student to do a verb, so *"Keep workout a little bit more"* should be "Keep **working out** a little bit more."

Comment: Thank you for your answer!  When I use the preposition 'to' it seems that I'm saying that I want him and don't want to leave him while I want to convey that I'm not going to give him a discount in the workout,  training or practice.  What do you have to say about that?

Comment: It's not idiomatic to use the preposition **to** in this context, and a native speaker wouldn't understand "give up *to* you" to mean what you want.  Saying "giving up *to* X" would mean that you are defeated by X or are surrendering to X, but that's not what you mean.

Answer (score 1):

You'd say "I won't give up on you," or "I'm not giving up on you."